# How would we like to describe ourselves?

Tags: discussion, scope

Currently our site is described as:

> "Q&A for materials modelers and data scientists"

This was chosen by Robert Cartaino during Area51, with no input from our community.

I think it's about time we update this.

This is how it looks on the [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) page, which also shows a lower bound on the number of characters we would be allowed, based on how long the description is on at least one other site:

[image]

Comment: Semi-related, this was the text I put at the top of the [Tour page](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/tour) (mods can edit this, I believe the overall site description might require the CMs): "Matter Modeling Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for Matter Modelers: computational chemists, material scientists, particle physicists, data scientists, and anyone else who uses computational methods to study molecules and materials."

Comment: I like the list that @Tyberius gives. I'd add "biomolecular simulators" or something along those lines -- when I first saw the site, I thought it was exclusive materials-focused; my experience on the site is that biomolecular folks are definitely welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can find a way to describe ourselves (all matter modelers) in a concise, unified manner.

We want to be inclusive of those who study atomic and molecular physics, theoretical and computational chemistry, condensed matter and materials physics, biophysics as well as comp molecular bio, and computer science, informatics, data-science, and mathematics applied to any of the mentioned fields. As MMSE matures, it is becoming a community of all who engage in mathematical and computational modeling of matter, from the subatomic to the thermodynamic limit.

So, I propose:

> Q&A for the scientific communities of the theoretical and computational physical and natural sciences, that focuses on unravelling the properties of matter from the subatomic to the macroscopic scales using quantitative methods.

Comment: Have we had any questions about the subatomic scale?

Comment: @Anyon none yet that have stayed open. I'd consider these in scope, but we just haven't attracted people (yet) who can reasonably ask/answer in this area.